# How to make flutter splash screen with different image? [A Question]

Tags: flutter, dart, splash-screen

I have to make different splash screen with different image, but this image is currently on native folder. This project is consists a python file code that functioning to run different `MainPage`, so when I build debug, it will make different app logo (from image inside native folder) based on what main page that I want to run. How to make different splash screen with image that same as app logo, does it need to be done with different programming language like `python` or `XML` file in android or is it possible to be done in `flutter` only?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flavors and Schemas for it.

[https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors\](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors%5C)
https://itnext.io/flutter-new-app-setup-with-flavors-in-one-go-331471b127e3